# SDLC and Software Process

Tags: analysis, sdlc, waterfall, rup

I have some confusion about the terms SDLC and Software Process. With respect to these (and more or less similar) terms, a have a few question.

1. What is the difference between SDLC and Software Process ?  (I understand SDLC is not just Waterfall).
2. Can we map SDLC with Unified Process ?
3. About the activities- Analysis in tradition waterfall model, Do we do Analysis in Unified Process (Any unified process- Agile or Rational) ?

Comment: Software Process covers engineering standards, whereas the SDLC refers to the process used by the entire organization to get things done and keep things running.

Answer (score 1):

SDLC stands for System Development Life Cycle, and it is a more or less generic term to describe whatever standard life cycle that you have implemented is.

SDLC is essentially your software process, but in my experience, most people associate it more directly with waterfall processes, as you indicated and more specifically, CMMI standards.

Typically with the SDLC, you will find that different groups have different methodologies to express it.

Since I don't recall the exact definition, there may be more linking it to the waterfall methods than just semantics. For instance, I believe Agile methodologies could be considered a type of SDLC, but I could be wrong about that.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Davis for your reply. You didn't commented on how System analysis is carried out in Agile or any other Unified process. I would definitely want to here on that as well. Thanks.  -Vipul.

Answer (score 1):

**SDLC** in shortcut for software development life cycle for a software product that contains the process for a product the software from requirement software.. maintenance
the SDLC  that contain viruses methodologies like waterfall ,scream,agile   that follow each the process software from the requirement , design, implementation, testing, maintains but
different to how to apply this process some methodologies  as agile do the multi-process in same time as implementation with  design in want to write Document.
in a waterfall, methodology cont go to apply the next process until the previous process finish  cont do mult process at the same time example cont be go implementation with the design in the same time you should be complete the design process cont be execution 2 process at same time

Answer (score 1):

**Software Process** - is a set of activities and associated results that produce a software product. There are 4 fundamental process activities that are common to all software processes

- Software Specification
- Software Development
- Software Validation
- Software Evolution

**SDLC** - is the oldest and the most widely used approach in software engineering.It follows a number of sequential phases and partitioned set of activities. Based in an engineering/construction/production new.

- Problem exploration
- Feasibility Study
- Requirement Gathering
- Analysis
- Design
- Construction
- IS implementation
- Operation and Maintenance
- Evoluation

  ### - Phase out

I very much agree with you, SDLC dates back to the 1950s and it was the first framework introduced at the time. However, I have a few notes on the SDLC phases - I'd say that there are 7 stages of the SDLC:
1.Planning
2. Requirements Analysis
3. Design
4. Development
5. Testing 
6. Deployment
7. Maintenance and improvement.

Today, there are a lot of SDLC models, Waterfall being the most popular one. Though, Agile is becoming quite popular lately - yet, I find a lot of teams to be highly disappointed of Agile. "We are constantly changing things that we never get anything done" - that's the most common phrase I hear.

Comment: Although I have no practical experience yet, only being in my third year of college and not having worked in my field yet, I would conjecture based on an article I read and my own reasoning that part of the problem with agile that leads to disappointment is misapplication. When designing anything, you have to realize that leaving things "incomplete" because "time's up", is inevitably going to lead to more work down the road. Imagine a city construction company leaving parts of a bridge 90% done and building on top of that incomplete foundation. Does that help the answer at all?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the difference between SDLC and Software Process ? (I understand SDLC is not just Waterfall).
   **Ans:** SDLC is the development lifecycle that is used in each and every project.SDLC defines all the standard phases which is very useful in software development. Software Process defines all the activities/phases to improve the quality of the product.

**Software process** is the testing lifecycle as it includes all the phases even the basic phases.

2. Can we map SDLC with Unified Process?
   **Ans:** Yes you can map but only methodologies not the life cycle

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear these queries one by one.

1. The difference between SDLC and Software Process:
   Software Process or Software Development Process and Software Development Life Cycle - both are the concepts with a similar goal to develop a software.

There are multiple strategies or models available to develop a software. Like, Waterfall, agile, etc.

SDLC provides set of phases for the developers to follow. Each phase is a result of the privious phase.

The Unified Software Development Process or Unified Process is an iterative and incremental software development process framework.

For more details:
software process: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/software-processes-in-software-engineering/
Software development life cycle: https://www.tatvasoft.com/outsourcing/2022/09/sdlc-best-practices.html

2. Yes, we can map SDLC with unified process.
   You can go through this link for more details: https://www2.cdc.gov/cdcup/library/framework/mapping.htm
3. Unified Process, like most agile techniques, does not expect the general project plan defines when each use case is going to be implemented. So, object oriented analysis is required for the disign of the Information System.
   For more details, use this reference: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/unified-process